# Multi-line text is not centered

Tags: flutter, centering

I am developing my first flutter app, trying to center a text. The following shows the screen with a short text, it is like expected:

[image]

If the text is longer and it spans on more lines, the output is the following:

[image]

The expected output would be:

[image]

The code snippet:

```
Column(
    children: snapshot.data!
        .map(
          (memberData) => Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Text(
                    "memberData.name memberData.name memberData.name",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  memberData.id.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Text(
                  memberData.userRole,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                child: QrImage(
                  data: memberData.uuid.toString(),
                  version: QrVersions.auto,
                  size: 150.0,
                ),
              ),
              memberData == snapshot.data!.last
                  ? Container()
                  : const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        )
        .toList(),
)
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `Text('text', textAlign: TextAlign.center)`

Comment: Oh man, i tried sooo many things but I missed that simple one....
It works, thanks.